# How to specify setup and teardown in Selenium On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium

I use Selenium On Rails to do some acceptance test, but before most of tests I need to create some binary test files associated with fixtures, and after each test - remove them.
I don't know how to do it. I was searching some kind of setup/teardown functions but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Usually people use an acceptance test framework like [Webrat](http://github.com/brynary/webrat) and set it up to use selenium. To configure Webrat to use selenium, this is how you would set it up in `test_helper.rb` :

```
require "webrat"

Webrat.configure do |config|
 config.mode = :selenium
end
```

Then I would define my setup and teardown in the test code. Would you be interested with this approach?

Comment: It sounds promising... Does webrat have build-in Selenium or I have to keep Selenium on Rails anyway?

Comment: The problem with Webrat is that I can't click button (e.g. calling javascript) because it doesn't provide adequate methods... Can I configure Webrat to use Selenium On Rails methods?

Comment: Yes you can mimic click_button and click_link with Webrat.

Comment: But Webrat's click_button only sees submit button which is not enough for me.

Comment: So you need to mimic `<button>` for ajax functions? Why can't you use submit button?

Comment: Because submit button is connected with form tag which I dont't use. It's simple button tag to js function (not ajax), which I have to test. To sum up: I need full acccess to Selenium commands (described in Selenium reference) and some Rails support in order to do setup and teardown.